# How to get module's title in Joomla 2.5?

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

Inside my module (from within php code), say mod_mymodule, how can I retrieve my module's title, in case an administrator has changed it from the module management page?

Is it possible to retrieve the "Status" and "Position" the same way as the title?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Inside the module, there are two helpful variables available:
`$module` and `$params`.

You are looking for `$module->title`.

Answer (score 12):

Try the below code.

```
<?php
  if ($module->showtitle) 
  {
    echo '<h2>' .$module->title .'</h2>';
  }
?>
```

You can access the following things.

```
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 18
    [title] => Login Form
    [module] => mod_login
    [position] => left
    [content] => 
    [showtitle] => 1
    [control] => 
    [params] => greeting=1
                name=0
    [user] => 0
    [name] => login
    [style] => 
)
```

Reference Joomla URL:
1. http://docs.joomla.org/JModuleHelper/getModule
2. http://docs.joomla.org/Customising_the_way_modules_are_displayed

> Updates - 22nd Dec 2016

You can use `jimport` to get the module.

```
jimport( 'joomla.application.module.helper' );
$module = JModuleHelper::getModule( 'login' ); // Single
$module = JModuleHelper::getModule( 'mainmenu', 'Resources' ); // Multiple
```